# Why is my ACM Certificate still not issued / validated?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl-certificate, amazon-elb, amazon-route53, aws-certificate-manager

I want to use this newly requested certificate further in the process with Load Balancer etc. But my certificate is still not issued. I have done the following steps:

1. I bought & registered a new domain name in `AWS Route 53`.
2. I created a new Hosted zone with the `sample.com` as domain name (same as the domain name in step 1).
3. I went to **AWS Certificate Manager** and requested a new public certificate with the following details: put in the domain name from step 1 in the input field of `Fully qualified domain name`. Added another name to this certificate `(*.sample.com)`. Used `DNS validation`, and the key algorithm as `RSA 2048`.
4. Once this is done, I clicked on the newly requested certificate and then on `Create the records in Route 53`. I can find the records in the Hosted zone of the domain.

After all the steps and waiting for hours, the status is still on `Pending validation`. Did I do something wrong?

Comment: Try looking up the ACM validation record here: https://mxtoolbox.com/DNSLookup.aspx It's likely that your NS records for your Route53 hosted zone need to be updated in your Route53 domain.

Comment: @MarkB when using your link to look for my Domain, it says it couldn't find any servers for my domain. Am I missing a step after buying/registering a new domain via Route 53?

Comment: Yes, you are missing the step of configuring the Route53 hosted zone's NS servers with the registrar (which is also Route53), as I mentioned in my first comment. You have to copy the NS record values over from the hosted zone page to the domains page.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options to validate an ACM certificate.

1. CDN validation
2. Route53 validation (easier and faster, also recommended by aws).

So, after applying for a certificate it will redirect you to the ACM dashboard. Reload the page and you'll see your certificate listed as `pending validation`.
Click on your desired pending certificate and scroll a little down. Click on what says `create record`, the  your domain name(or names) will automatically be selected and hit again `create record`. Your record(s) will be created in route53 and the certificates will be issued.

> Note: after creating record once if certificate is still not issued create record again, it'll overwrite records and will solve the issue.

Good luck!